# Is there any way that class's destructor isn't called when process is finished in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor

I want to know destrucor(`__del__`) isn't called when program is finished.

How to adjust `__del__` ?

For examples,

```
class destruct:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(f"(initializing {self.name}...)")

    def __del__(self):
        print(f"(Destroying {self.name} ...)")


test1 = destruct('a')
test2 = destruct('b')
```

that code's result :

```
(initializing a...)
(initializing b...)
(Destroying a ...)  <- I don't want to printing this message
(Destroying b ...)  <- I don't want to printing this message
```

Comment: Why? What do you think will be a benefit from this?

Comment: finished process can't keep it in memory. If you want to keep some data then you would have to save data in file and read it when you restart process.

Comment: Perhaps you explain when `__del__` should be called and when `__del__` should not be called.

Why is it a problem to call `__del__` when the program ends.

Then we might perhaps propose a solution for your scenario

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `__del__` is to be called whenever an object is deleted.

With C-Python objects are deleted if their reference counter is 0, which is normally at the end of a functions scope or also when a program finished.

If you do not want this behavior, then do not use `__del__`, but implement some other explicit mechanism.

We might advise if you give more details about your exact context.

Answer (score 0):

methods like this *should* always be called by the Python runtime at the appropriate times.  there are a few times if/when this won't happen:

- the machine is turned off!  always good to bear in mind if you're writing code that touches resources like the disk or network
- the process is terminated abruptly.  e.g. `kill -9 pid` in unix, or "force quit" in windows
- a debugger or other native code intervenes
- some other code "monkey patches" your class/object to do something else

there are probably other ways as well